# Lidando com arquivos compactados em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso resolver o seguinte problema com PHP: o usuário irá fazer upload de um arquivo zip contendo centenas (possivelmente milhares) de arquivos. Eu devo descompactar esses arquivos em um certo diretório e, após isso, devo iterar sobre o nome (preciso do nome!) de cada arquivo arquivo descompactado para realizar um conjunto de operacoes sobre esse arquivo. Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta em PHP para lidar com esse tipo de problema?

Answer (score 1):

Extrair arquivos em PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Obter conteúdo de um diretório: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php

Você também pode usar comandos do teu sistema, se preferir: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php